# asp.net Chart control - Pie Chart - Text around/outside piechart with tooltip

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am having a requirement, where I need to have a pie-chart, i need text around pie-chart , the text should be a hyperlink.

Ex: we have 3 three fields A,B,C. A's ratio is 30%, B's ratio is 40%, c's ratio is 30%

So pie chart gets divided into 3 parts, outside the graph , we should get the label A(in A's area only), when we point on , tool tip should say

"A's ratio is 30 %'. 
I am working in .Net 3.5, VS 2008, using MS chart control(added explicitly by executing MSChart.exe.

Thanks in Advance

Ram

Answer (score 5):

```
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "outside";
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieStartAngle"] = "90";
```

this should do the trick for putting them outside... i am still looking for how to get the hyperlink feature... hope it helps.. put this in ur code behind..